# How to locate which programmatically created button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am doing an application on a Multiple Choice Question (MCQ) where I have to get questions, answers from a webservice. I have 1 question with 4 options, among the 4 options, I have 1 correct answer. Each of the options, I created a button programmatically. This is how I did it:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(40, yButton, 30, 30);
    [button setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(correctPressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [buttonArray addObject:button];
```

How many options I have in a questions will determine how many buttons will be created. Now when I want to show an indication that when a certain button is clicked, that button needs to stay highlighted until I decides to change my answer. I have done a few approaches.

I used `IndexPath`, hoping I could use `indexPath.row` like in `TableView`. It didnt work out at all. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<[videolistArray count];i++){


    NSArray *myWords = [[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"video"] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[myWords lastObject]);

    UIButton *guitaristButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    guitaristButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, ycomp, 300, 35);
    guitaristButton.tag = i;
    [guitaristButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green-buttons.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [guitaristButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [guitaristButton setTitle:[myWords lastObject] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [guitaristButton addTarget:self action:@selector(VideoButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[guitaristButton performSelector:<#(SEL)aSelector#> withObject:<#(id)object1#> withObject:<#(id)object2#>
    [videoScrollView addSubview:guitaristButton];
    [guitaristButton release];

    ycomp = ycomp+35;   
}
videoScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(300, ycomp);
```

}
-(void)VideoButtonSelected:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSArray *myWords = [[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] valueForKey:@"video"] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[myWords lastObject]);
    [setAlarmVedioButton setTitle:[myWords lastObject] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [videoNameButtonView removeFromSuperview];
    vedioString=[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag] valueForKey:@"video"] ;
}

in above code me make uibutton with help of array count and when i select any button then it display the same text value of array on last button

Answer (score 1):

Change this to

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(correctPressed)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [buttonArray addObject:button];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(correctPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [buttonArray addObject:button];
```

now in your selector you will get a reference to the button.

eg.

```
UIButton * lastButtonPressed = nil;
-(void) correctPressed:(UIButton *) theButton{
   [theButton setHighlighted:YES];
   if(lastButtonPressed) [lastButtonPressed setHighlighted:NO];
   lastButtonPressed =  theButton;

}
```

** You may want to use the selected Method for buttons. So you can set a button selected instead.

I just typed this code, check my @selector change and that setHighlighted is actually correct but you should get the idea.

Now your code will call the selector and it should have a reference to the calling button.

John.

Comment: Thanks John, will try the code out. Can you explain to me why you use `(UIButton *)theButton` for?

Comment: Edit: I have tried the code out and it works, but not the way I kinda want it to. I wanted it to be highlighted until I tap other buttons or itself again. `[theButton setHighlighted:YES]` will become `NO` when I release my finger.

Comment: I feel like I am bothering you, sorry John. But it is still not working. Does it work for you? When you tap on the button, it remains highlighted when you release your finger?

Answer (score 0):

Its alright, I solved this issue.

What I did was did a `button.tag = number; number++` somewhere in the codes. By using tagging methods, I then can keep track in the `arrays` which button is clicked.

```
-(void)correctAnswer
{
   yButton += 50;
   yLabel += 50;

   label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, yLabel, 150, 30)];
   label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [label setText:Option];
   [labelArray addObject:label];
   [self addSubview:label];

   button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(40, yButton, 30, 30);
   button.tag = idx;
   NSLog(@"-------====== Tag Index is: %i", idx);
   UIImage * btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedCheckbox.png"];
   [button setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(correctPressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [buttonArray addObject:button];
idx++;
[self addSubview:button];

}


-(void)correctPressed:(id)sender {

int but =  (int)[(UIButton*)sender tag];

if(correctValue) {
    UIImage * btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedCheckbox.png"];
    UIButton *btn1 = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:but];
    [btn1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    correctValue = NO;

} else {
    UIImage * btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedCheckbox.png"];
    UIButton *btn2 = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:but];
    [btn2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    correctValue = YES;
} 

NSLog(@"Correct answer!!");    
}
```